How to use this in nestjs decorator
I want to set the file limit on upload using
new MaxFileSizeValidator({ maxSize: this.configService.get<number>('uploadLimit') }),

and I receive configService on controller
  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {}

The problem that I have currently is that I get an error on
this.configService.get<number>('uploadLimit')

Saying that Object is possibly 'undefined'. I found this solution, but is it somehow possible to fix it without implementing custom interceptor or anything complex?
